# Changing constant in widthAnchor changes the way uicollectionviewcells behave

Tags: ios, swift

I have this constraint in my swift code:

```
wrapper.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

And in this wrapper i also have a uicollectionview. In cellForItemAt I have the following code:

```
print(comments.count)
```

Now when when I add `constant:-20`  to the width constraint the print statement does not execute and the cell's are not visible. How is it possible that changing design affects the back-end?

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warning messages in debug console?

Comment: @DonMag no i don't

Comment: UICollectionView only calls `cellForItemAt` if there are one or more cells that can be displayed. Is it possible that by making the view 20-pts narrower, you can no longer fit even one cell in the available space?

Comment: @DonMag i set UICollectionView's to contentsize.height and also i'm sure it's able to fit them all

Comment: What happens if you use `constant: -1`? or `constant: -5`? or `constant: 10`?